# Missing Azure accelerated networking interfaces while VMs initializes

Tags: azure, azure-networking, mellanox, sr-iov

I'm running my application on top of Azure Ubuntu 16.04 VMs (Wrapped as a VHD image).
In several cases I have observed missing SRIOV associated VFs interfaces, while VMs were starting.
Need to mention that this issue isn't repetitive, but it happen in several Standard_F8s_v2 instances we have deployed in our labs.

VMs are attached with 3 network interfaces, 2 of them are set with accelerated network attributes. Instances are being deployed using Terraform scripts.

Below you can see serial console snippet, where "enp2s2" & "enp3s3" VF interfaces, dpdk net_failsafe based are missing, whilst additional console snippet, from another reboot, shows that they exist.
I was suspecting that the issue was related to Mellanox kernel modules initialization sequences, but I have gathered many VMs startup statistics which couldn't point out that this is the RCA.
In addition, tried to shutdown/restart devices from Azure portal and by reboot VMs via ssh, but still was able to see the problem.

**Following missing interfaces snippet:** (Can be seen missing under "ci-info: Net Device" list)

*`[    1.961519] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.961992] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.966624] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    2.013574] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_netvsc
[    2.017652] hv_utils: Registering HyperV Utility Driver
[    2.021791] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_util
[    2.026534] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.031197] hv_vmbus: registering driver hyperv_keyboard
[    2.035793] hv_vmbus: registering driver hid_hyperv
[    2.041572] hv_vmbus: registering driver hyperv_fb
[    2.048342] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    2.052076] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    4.344565] hv_utils: Shutdown IC version 3.0
[    4.348061] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/device:07/VMBUS:01/d34b2567-b9b6-42b9-8778-0a4ec0b955bf/serio2/input/input3
[    4.358187] input: Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse as /devices/0006:045E:0621.0001/input/input4
[    4.364222] hid 0006:045E:0621.0001: input: <UNKNOWN> HID v0.01 Mouse [Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse] on 
[    4.371502] hyperv_fb: Screen resolution: 1152x864, Color depth: 32
[    4.378396] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 144x54
[    4.383835] hv_utils: VSS IC version 5.0
[    5.560104] hv_utils: Heartbeat IC version 3.0
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... [    6.624015] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 11383 MB/s
[    6.672008] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  8608 MB/s
[    6.720013] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 14144 MB/s
[    6.768008] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  9824 MB/s
[    6.816009] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 15697 MB/s
[    6.864007] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 11120 MB/s
[    6.912010] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 20281 MB/s
[    6.960008] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 16369 MB/s
[    7.008009] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 25744 MB/s
[    7.056007] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 17842 MB/s
[    7.104010] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 27707 MB/s
[    7.152008] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 19589 MB/s
[    7.200010] raid6: avx512x1 gen() 25916 MB/s
[    7.248010] raid6: avx512x1 xor() 15400 MB/s
[    7.296008] raid6: avx512x2 gen() 31486 MB/s
[    7.344010] raid6: avx512x2 xor() 19259 MB/s
[    7.392009] raid6: avx512x4 gen() 32802 MB/s
[    7.440008] raid6: avx512x4 xor() 19748 MB/s
[    7.442786] raid6: using algorithm avx512x4 gen() 32802 MB/s
[    7.446455] raid6: .... xor() 19748 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    7.449751] raid6: using avx512x2 recovery algorithm
[    7.454113] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx

[    7.459720] async_tx: api initialized (async)
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... [    7.500972] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
done.
Warning: fsck not present, so skipping root file system
[    7.621580] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[    7.716053] random: crng init done
[    7.718135] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[    7.754028] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard
Cloud-init v. 19.2-24-ge7881d5c-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 running 'init-local' at Sun, 06 Oct 2019 11:06:31 +0000. Up 8.04 seconds.
cloud-init-nonet[8.59]: static networking is now up
Cloud-init v. 19.2-24-ge7881d5c-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 running 'init' at Sun, 06 Oct 2019 11:06:32 +0000. Up 8.80 seconds.
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Device |  Up  |           Address           |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: |  eth0  | True |         10.29.50.32         | 255.255.255.0 | global | 00:0d:3a:38:c1:f7 |
ci-info: |  eth0  | True | fe80::20d:3aff:fe38:c1f7/64 |       .       |  link  | 00:0d:3a:38:c1:f7 |
ci-info: |  eth1  | True |         10.29.115.10        | 255.255.255.0 | global | 00:0d:3a:38:c3:06 |
ci-info: |  eth1  | True | fe80::20d:3aff:fe38:c306/64 |       .       |  link  | 00:0d:3a:38:c3:06 |
ci-info: |  eth2  | True |         10.29.211.10        | 255.255.255.0 | global | 00:0d:3a:38:c9:4a |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |          127.0.0.1          |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |           ::1/128           |       .       |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+`

**Another snippet where interfaces are shown:**

`[    1.990765] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.991261] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.995831] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    2.042179] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_netvsc
[    2.042182] hv_utils: Registering HyperV Utility Driver
[    2.050908] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_util
[    2.055113] hv_vmbus: registering driver hyperv_keyboard
[    2.059757] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.066167] hv_vmbus: registering driver hid_hyperv
[    2.073141] hv_vmbus: registering driver hyperv_fb
[    2.082086] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    2.086060] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    3.200601] hv_utils: Heartbeat IC version 3.0
[    3.204903] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/device:07/VMBUS:01/d34b2567-b9b6-42b9-8778-0a4ec0b955bf/serio2/input/input3
[    3.219127] input: Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse as /devices/0006:045E:0621.0001/input/input4
[    3.226095] hid 0006:045E:0621.0001: input: <UNKNOWN> HID v0.01 Mouse [Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse] on 
[    3.234239] hyperv_fb: Screen resolution: 1152x864, Color depth: 32
[    3.241442] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 144x54
[    3.388646] hv_utils: Shutdown IC version 3.0
[    3.391537] hv_utils: VSS IC version 5.0
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... [    4.688013] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 11377 MB/s
[    4.736006] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  8608 MB/s
[    4.784008] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 14143 MB/s
[    4.832012] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  9799 MB/s
[    4.880013] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 15731 MB/s
[    4.928012] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 11084 MB/s
[    4.976012] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 20223 MB/s
[    5.024009] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 16357 MB/s
[    5.072009] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 25798 MB/s
[    5.120011] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 17831 MB/s
[    5.168009] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 27715 MB/s
[    5.216010] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 18555 MB/s
[    5.264012] raid6: avx512x1 gen() 27142 MB/s
[    5.312011] raid6: avx512x1 xor() 15413 MB/s
[    5.360011] raid6: avx512x2 gen() 31448 MB/s
[    5.408010] raid6: avx512x2 xor() 19311 MB/s
[    5.456012] raid6: avx512x4 gen() 32843 MB/s
[    5.504011] raid6: avx512x4 xor() 20650 MB/s
[    5.506896] raid6: using algorithm avx512x4 gen() 32843 MB/s
[    5.510878] raid6: .... xor() 20650 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    5.514425] raid6: using avx512x2 recovery algorithm
[    5.519051] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx

[    5.525076] async_tx: api initialized (async)
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... [    5.563208] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
done.
Warning: fsck not present, so skipping root file[    5.680481] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
 system
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[    5.803547] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard
[    5.825023] Adding 614396k swap on /var/cache/swap/swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:8 across:1114108k FS
[    5.980054] random: crng init done
[    5.982620] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
Cloud-init v. 19.2-24-ge7881d5c-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 running 'init-local' at Sun, 06 Oct 2019 12:06:17 +0000. Up 6.10 seconds.
cloud-init-nonet[6.73]: static networking is now up
Cloud-init v. 19.2-24-ge7881d5c-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 running 'init' at Sun, 06 Oct 2019 12:06:18 +0000. Up 6.97 seconds.
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Device |  Up  |           Address           |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: | **enp2s2** | **True** |              .              |       .       |   .    | 00:0d:3a:38:c3:06 |
ci-info: | **enp3s3** | **True** |              .              |       .       |   .    | 00:0d:3a:38:c9:4a |
ci-info: |  eth0  | True |         10.29.50.32         | 255.255.255.0 | global | 00:0d:3a:38:c1:f7 |
ci-info: |  eth1  | True |         10.29.115.10        | 255.255.255.0 | global | 00:0d:3a:38:c3:06 |
ci-info: |  eth1  | True | fe80::20d:3aff:fe38:c306/64 |       .       |  link  | 00:0d:3a:38:c3:06 |
ci-info: |  eth2  | True |         10.29.211.10        | 255.255.255.0 | global | 00:0d:3a:38:c9:4a |
ci-info: |  eth2  | True | fe80::20d:3aff:fe38:c94a/64 |       .       |  link  | 00:0d:3a:38:c9:4a |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |          127.0.0.1          |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |           ::1/128           |       .       |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+`